# How to disable a scroll bar in a html file

Tags: html

How to disable a scroll bar in a html file ...when i double click on the html file, i dont want the html to load with scroll bars

Thanks
regards 
- Miss subanki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling a scroll bar in a Frame in a Web Browser can be done with CSS

```
<iframe class="dnb" src="http://dotnetblogger.com" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
<style>
    iframe.dnb{overflow:hidden;}
<style>
```

As per your edit, you can do the same thing in a standard page by disabling scroll bars in the body

```
body{overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: thanx it is the exact answer....although i saw ur post after i figured it out. anyways thanx in helping me out.

Comment: You can do this same stuff with javascript setting the css, but I don't think you want to complicate this anymore...?